# boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator multithreaded safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, thread-safety

I have a program that uses at least two threads to operate on a single directory. One adds and removes files from it, second counts its size like that:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
    size_t size=0;
    if(fs::exists("/home/user/Documents/my_directory") && fs::is_directory("/home/user/Documents/my_directory"))
    {
        try{
            for(auto entry: fs::recursive_directory_iterator("/home/user/Documents/my_directory"))
            {
                if(fs::is_regular_file(entry.status()))
                {
                    size += fs::file_size(entry);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(boost::filesystem::filesystem_error e)
        {
            std::cout << e.code() << std::endl;
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
            std::cout << e.path1() << std::endl;
            std::cout << e.path2() << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    std::cout << size << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Single threaded it works fine, but when some other threads mess with the files i am getting `filesystem_error bad descriptor` and cannot read any size at all.

My question: is there any way of taking some kind of thread safe snapshot of the directory to count it's size or maybe other way to iterate through all the files ignoring single bad descriptors and get more or less accurate size?

@edit: the error i am trying to avoid is boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::operator++: Bad file descriptor: "/home/user/Documents/my_directory"

Comment: Just catch and ignore the error and continue onto the next file? Or as you are expecting an error possibly better to use the overload with an error code rather than using exceptions

Comment: so you are suggesting that instead of return 0 there should be continue statement? i cannot do that since try is wrapped over the for loop. Could you also provide the solution with error code overload?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to just ignore any errors:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
    uintmax_t size=0;
    if(fs::exists("/home/user/Documents/my_directory") && fs::is_directory("/home/user/Documents/my_directory"))
    {
        try{
            for(auto entry: fs::recursive_directory_iterator("/home/user/Documents/my_directory"))
            {
                if(fs::is_regular_file(entry.status()))
                {
                    boost::system::error_code ec;
                    uintmax_t fileSize = fs::file_size(entry, ec);
                    if (!ec)
                    {
                        size += fileSize;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(boost::filesystem::filesystem_error e)
        {
            std::cout << e.code() << std::endl;
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
            std::cout << e.path1() << std::endl;
            std::cout << e.path2() << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    std::cout << size << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You might still get exceptions from `recursive_directory_iterator` if a directory is deleted.

Comment: doesn't work, still getting boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::operator++: Bad file descriptor: "/home/user/Documents/my_directory"